# swagger post body without schema

Tags: node.js, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I am using node-swagger. It's working fine. I want to post json body without defining the schema in details. For example below I don't want to specify object properties. Is there any way to do this?

```
/pets:
 post:
 description: Add new
 parameters:
  - name: id
   in: body
   description: data to post
   required: true
   type: object
 responses:
  '200':
    description: A list of pets
    schema:
      type : string
```

It's not rendering the textarea to post json data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this YAML:

```
---
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  version: 0.0.0
  title: Simple API
paths:
  /:
    post:
      produces:
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - in: body
          name: id
          required: true
          schema: 
            "$ref": "#/definitions/inBody"
      responses:
        201:
          description: Added
definitions:
  inBody:
    type: object
```

Comment: There is also a problem with node-swagger module. It does not show textarea without defining schema object properties. So I used node-swagger with swgger-ui. Now it's working fine. Thanks Sampada

Comment: glad to be of help!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `swagger-ui-express` and `swagger-jsdoc` and don't wan to use definitions you can directly define in YAML on endpoint like this.

```
/**
 * @swagger
 * /pets:
 *   post:
 *     description: Add new
 *     produces:
 *       - application/json
 *     parameters:
 *       - name: id
 *         description: data to post
 *         in: body
 *         required: true
 *         schema:
 *           type: object
 *     responses:
 *       201:
 *         description: Pet created
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Open API 3 spec, for an empty body request, you should have a `requestBody` section like the following:

```
   requestBody:
     required: true
       description: blabla.
         content:
            application/json:
                schema:
                   type: object
                   nullable: true
```